# Как конвертировать дату в виде 2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z в формат 15 сентября(дата + название месяца)?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как конвертировать дату в виде 2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z в формат 15 сентября(дата + название месяца)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так :

```js
var month = [
  'Января',
  'Февраля',
  'Марта',
  'Апреля',
  'Мая',
  'Июня',
  'Июля',
  'Августа',
  'Сентября',
  'Октября',
  'Ноября',
  'Декабря'
];

var d = new Date('2017-09-01T21:00:00.000Z');
var newDate = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ' ' + month[d.getMonth()];

console.log(newDate);
```