# Как вывести последний день месяца и сам месяц текстом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью jquery вывести последний день месяца, и сам месяц?

Например:

сейчас 23.02.2021 - выводим 28 февраля;
сейчас 10.03.2021 - выводим 31 марта.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let date = new Date();
let firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
let lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(firstDay.getDate(), lastDay.getDate());

//----------------------------------------------------//
let month = 1; // Февраль
let year = 2020;
date = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(firstDay.getDate(), lastDay.getDate());


/* сейчас 23.02.2021 - выводим 28 февраля; сейчас 10.03.2021 - выводим 31 марта.*/
date = new Date(2021, 1, 23);
lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
console.log(lastDay.getDate());

date = new Date(2021, 2, 10);
lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
console.log(lastDay.getDate());
```

---

По поводу названия месяца, есть ответ: **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721536/191482**

Answer (score 0):

С `jQuery` не знаю с `moment` можно примерно так:

```js
const d1 = moment("23.02.2021", "DDMMYYYY")
  .endOf("month")
  .toDate()
  .toLocaleDateString("ru", { day: "numeric", month: "long" });
const d2 = moment("10.03.2021", "DDMMYYYY")
  .endOf("month")
  .toDate()
  .toLocaleDateString("ru", { day: "numeric", month: "long" });

console.log("d1", d1);
console.log("d2", d2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```